# Как с помощью python tkinter изменить курсор на время пока окно tkinter активно

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cursor

1. Как можно в Windows 10 изменить курсор на картинку на время, пока
   окно `tkinter` открыто?
2. Какого формата должна быть картинка
   (подойдет ли .ico)?
3. Надо чтоб курсор был изменен также за пределами
   окна `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы изменить курсор, можно использовать эту команду:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.config(cursor="plus")
```

К сожалению, можно поставить курсор, только из стандартных.
Список курсоров:

[image]

Comment: курсор меняеться только когда он внутри окна tkinter